# Loops question (python): Variable not evaluating correctly

Tags: python, loops

Please why does print(lovescore) show 4 instead of 3?

```
name1 = "Ikechukwu"

word1 = "Ike"
lovescore = 0

i = 0
while i < len(word1):
  for letter in name1:
    if word1[i] == letter:
      lovescore +=1


  i += 1
print(lovescore)
```

(It won't let me post without adding more text. So just adding this as filler)

Comment: Why do you expect 3? `k` appears twice, which will add two to the total score.

Comment: Based on the fact that you're expecting the answer to be '3'.  You need to add `continue` after `lovescore += 1` with the same indentation.  You're saying "I'm done with the letter and there's no need to look further; let's move onto the next letter."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The letter `k` appears twice in `name1`, so `word1[i] == letter` will be True twice when `i` is 1.

You can change it to avoid duplicates this by adding `break` after `lovescore +=1` or by replacing the for loop with this:

```py
  if word1[i] in name1:
    lovescore += 1
```